# how to obtain the first record of the result of a subquery in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have to say that I am a very "beginner" user in respect to DB-world.

I have a table with the following columns, which types are : int and timestamp, respectively:

```
**foreign-key** | **date**
================|=========
 fk1            | timestamp1
 fk1            | timestamp2
 fk2            | timestamp3
 fk2            | timestamp4
 fk3            | timestamp5
```

I would like to obtain for each foreign-key **one record**, that contains the most **recent** timestamp.

I tried this command which didn't help me get the job done:

```
select * from (
    select * from table1 where foreign-key in (fk1,fk2,fk3) order by date DESC
) as t group by foreign-key;
```

The problem with this command, that it returned the oldest timestamp, not the most recent one!

Please note that the number of the foreign-keys in the subquery is arbitrary. This is why I use the `in` operator.

Thank you

Comment: I marked your question duplicate because the link explains how to solve your problem better than I probably could myself.  Basically, you'll need to learn about how to use `GROUP BY` to find the most recent timestamp for each foreign key.  And then, you might also need to do another join, if you want the full most recent record.

Comment: If you try a query and really get stuck, then drop a comment here, and someone can reopen the question.

Comment: You are right, The solution for this a query should look like:

`select * from (
    select * from table1 where foreign-key in (fk1,fk2,fk3) group by DATE(date) order by DATE(date) DESC
) as t group by foreign-key;`

where the `DATE()` function will extract the date out of the timestamp, and thus make the groups more relevant